# iPhone search text with regex

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, regex

I am using this Regex:

```
<li class=\"b_algo\"><h2><a href=\"(.*?)\"
```

To search in `NSString`. And i want to be able to use this search but add :

```
<li class=\"b_algo\">@GGGGG<h2><a href=\"(.*?)\"
```

The `@GGGGG` means that no matters which text' the `RegexKitLite` will ignore it, It's possible to do something like this?

Comment: mistake #1: using regex to parse html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
NSString *target = @"<li class=\"b_algo\">@GGGGG<h2><a href=\"http://test.xyz\" junk";
NSString *regEx  = @"<li class=\"b_algo\">@[^<]+<h2><a href=\"([^\"]+)\"";

NSRange  searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [target length]);
NSError *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regEx options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:target options:0 range: searchedRange];

NSLog(@"target: %@", target);
NSLog(@"regEx:  %@", regEx);
NSLog(@"group1: %@", [target substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
```

Output:

```
target: <li class="b_algo">@GGGGG<h2><a href="http://test.xyz" junk
regEx:  <li class="b_algo">@[^<]+<h2><a href="(.*?)"
group1: http://test.xyz
```